# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer reads from XML File (Apache Commons Configuration)

Tags: java, spring, properties, apache-commons

Is there a possibility to configure the Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to read from
properties.xml, via Apache Commons Configuration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer-like class for use with Spring that accepts XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479855/is-there-a-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-like-class-for-use-with-spring-that-acce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution with the help of [seanizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163838/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-reads-from-xml-file-apache-commons-configuration/3165604#3165604) and [springmodule](https://springmodules.dev.java.net)

```
<!-- Composite configuration -->
<bean id="configuration" class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurations">
        <list>
            <!-- User specifics -->
            <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration">
                <constructor-arg type="java.net.URL" value="file:cfg.xml" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="configuration"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testConfig" class="uvst.cfg.TestConfiguration">
    <property name="domain" value="${some.prop}"></property>
</bean>
```

class TestConfiguration

```
public class TestConfiguration {
    private String domain;
    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }
    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }
}
```

jUnit Testclass

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( { "/applicationContextTest.xml" })

public class ApacheCommonCfg2Spring extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    private TestConfiguration tcfg;

    @Test
    public void configuration(){
        tcfg  = this.applicationContext.getBean("testConfig", TestConfiguration.class);
        System.out.println(tcfg.getDomain());
    }

}
```

Springmodule is rather old an it seems that it is not longer maintained, but it works with Spring 3.0.3.

feel free to copy & paste!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way (maybe not the nicest though) would be to subclass the PropertyPlaceholdeConfigurer, load the commons configuration there and then pass it to the superclass:

```
public class TestPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
{
    public TestPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess, Properties props)
            throws BeansException
    {
        XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("config.xml");
        Properties commonsProperties = config.getProperties("someKey")
        // Or something else with the configuration
        super.processProperties(beanFactoryToProcess, commonsProperties);
    }
}
```

Then you just use this class as the placeholderConfig:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig"
    class="com.exampl.TestPlaceholderConfigurer ">
    <!-- ... -->
</bean>
```

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on "It dosen't work". After all, Daff has put some effort in trying to answer your question.

Comment: That's true, it wasn't supposed to be a copy & paste answer (which is what I have to assume you did regarding your unhelpful reply and an uncommented downvote). As usual with answers here it is just a guide on how to solve your problem, if you have a specific question just post it as a reply.

Comment: I apologize for my nasty comment, you brought my on the right way!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [solution using spring modules](https://springmodules.dev.java.net/docs/reference/0.8/html_single/#d0e1056). I don't know how current this is, but even if it isn't you could probably easily take the code and make it work with current versions.