# Using placeholders in definition of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: web-services, spring, configuration, mule

**Background:**
I am using Mule to deploy large numbers of web services to multiple Mule instances.  I am using Spring to configure the services, and this is all working nicely with the configuration in properties files on the file system.  In order to ease the management of such a setup I want to move all the configuration to a web service, holding only the minimal bootstrap information on the file system.

This boot information consists of 2 parts:

1) the URI of the configuration service - this is passed in as a system property to Mule and is picked up correctly

2) the configuration realm - an additional identifier to allow an instance of a service to identify itself to the configuration service (for example, the instance of the catalogue service running on server dev-2).  This part cannot be coded into the Spring configuration (eg. by setting configRealm to catalogue-service) as each configuration service may be supplying configuration information to multiple instances of a given service (eg. catalogue service)

**Attempted solutions:**

1) a single overridden PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (I know, I know) with all the logic to decide encoded within

2) multiple PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers with different orders (one to handle file system properties, one to handle web service properties)

3) a custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor that implements Order

4) defined the WebServicePropertySource as @Configuration and explicitly referenced external file using @PropertySource (failed as Environment is not initialised at the point WebServicePropertySource is needed to resolve placeholders)

5) a single PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with a custom PropertySource to handle the web service properties and RespourcePropertySources to handle the file system properties

All of these approaches (apart from 4) have fallen down on the fact that I am using a placeholder in the definition of the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - the placeholder is not resolved and the realm that gets passed to the web service is ${catalogue-service-realm} or similar.

I know I can make this work by using a system property to define the config realm but as there may be quite a few services deployed in a Mule instance this is ugly and would require a server restart for any changes.

In the code below, I will restrict the example to the latest solution (5 above) as this uses the most up to date Spring 3.1 API.

**Excerpt from mule-config.xml:**

```
   <spring:bean id="configServiceHelper" class="config.client.GetConfigurationServiceHelper">
        <spring:property name="configRealm" value="${catalogue-service-realm}"/>
        <spring:property name="configServiceWsdlUrl" value="${configuration.service.url}"/>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean id="webServicePropertySource" class="config.client.WebServicePropertySource">
        <spring:constructor-arg name="name" value="web-service-property-source"/>
        <spring:constructor-arg name="helper" ref="configServiceHelper"/>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean id="propertySources" class="config.client.DefaultPropertySources">
        <spring:property name="propertySources">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:ref bean="webServicePropertySource"/>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

    <spring:bean class="config.client.LocationPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <spring:property name="propertySources" ref="propertySources"/>
        <spring:property name="locations">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>classpath*:spring/config/*.properties</spring:value>
                <spring:value>classpath:catalogue-service.properties</spring:value>
                <spring:value>classpath:catalogue-service-override.properties</spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
```

**Please note:** the behaviour of the config.client.LocationPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer differs from the default PropertySourcesPLaceholderConfigurer in that, instead of discarding the locations if propertySources is set, it adds them to the propertySources. Logging has confirmed that the list of propertySources comprises 14 elements at runtime (the web service property source plus 13 resources)

I am pretty sure that this excerpt succinctly illustrates what I am trying to do but if it doesn't, please ask for more details.   The crux of my problem is that the ${catalogue-service-realm} placeholder in the web service helper is not resolved from the information held in the properties files on the classpath.

This looks to me like a chicken and egg problem that there must be a simple solution too - I just don't know what it is so any help or pointers would be most gratefully appreciated :-)

Kind regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of my problem is that placeholders in the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean definition are not being resolved.

I have got around this by explicitly and manually resolving the placeholder in the problematic configRealm attribute definition.  It's not exactly elegant but it does avoid the need to use an additional configuration library as proposed by [Victor Romero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/912190/victor-romero) above.

Annotated Spring config below.

```
<!-- configRealm moved to webServicePropertySource to prevent 
     the need to pollute service client with Spring PropertyResolver -->
    <spring:bean id="configServiceHelper" class="config.client.GetConfigurationServiceHelper">
        <spring:property name="configServiceWsdlUrl" value="${configuration.service.url}"/>
    </spring:bean>

<!-- WebServicePropertySource now contains configRealm and a PropertyResolver to use
     to resolve the placeholder -->
    <spring:bean id="webServicePropertySource" class="config.client.WebServicePropertySource">
        <spring:constructor-arg name="name" value="web-service-property-source"/>
        <spring:constructor-arg name="helper" ref="configServiceHelper"/>
        <spring:constructor-arg name="realm" value="${bisac_genre_service.config_realm}"/>
        <spring:constructor-arg name="resolver" ref="propertyResolver"/>
    </spring:bean>

<!-- New class to wrap a bunch of resources into a PropertySource -->
    <spring:bean id="resourcePropertySource" class="config.client.ResourceAggregationPropertySource">
        <spring:constructor-arg name="name" value="resource-property-source"/>
        <spring:constructor-arg name="resources">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>classpath*:spring/config/*.properties</spring:value>
                <spring:value>classpath:genre-service.properties</spring:value>
                <spring:value>classpath:genre-service-override.properties</spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:constructor-arg>
    </spring:bean>

<!-- Standard PropertySourcesPropertyResolver defined to just use the 
     classpath resources for resolution -->
    <spring:bean id="propertyResolver" class="org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver">
        <spring:constructor-arg ref="resourcePropertySources"/>
    </spring:bean>

<!-- PropertySources consisting of just the filesystem resources -->
    <spring:bean id="resourcePropertySources" class="config.client.DefaultPropertySources">
        <spring:property name="propertySources">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:ref bean="resourcePropertySource"/>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

<!-- PropertySources consisting of the web service source plus
     the filesystem resources -->
    <spring:bean id="allPropertySources" class="config.client.DefaultPropertySources">
        <spring:property name="propertySources">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:ref bean="resourcePropertySource"/>
                <spring:ref bean="webServicePropertySource"/>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>

<!-- Vanilla Spring PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer using ALL PropertySources -->
    <spring:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <spring:property name="propertySources" ref="allPropertySources"/>
    </spring:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Spring Profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/)?

You can find a brief example about how to leverage them in mule [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Spring+3.1+Upgrade)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! I did look at Spring Profiles when examining the \@Configuration approach but they looked orthogonal to my problem - I think profiles would work if the service instances could be enumerated at compile time.  As we may have 20 service instances requiring unique configuration one day and 100 the next this is not really practical.  Could possibly also work if you could use a placeholder in the \@Profile - e.g. \@Profile("${catalogue-service-realm}") but I think I would have the same problems with that

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Configuration API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration//) supports [multi-tenant configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration//userguide/howto_multitenant.html#Multi-tenant_Configurations).

To integrate with Spring you could use some solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163838/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-reads-from-xml-file-apache-commons-configuration) or just leverage SpEL i.e: `@Property("expression")`.

Comment: Interesting - this would actually work because it would use something other than Spring configuration to do the bootstrap portion, so by the time the Spring PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer starts doing it's work with the web service it's already been configured by something else.  However, this would: 1) require the placeholders to be resolved manually 2) involve having 2 different configuration mechanisms (plus dependencies) in each service/application. Consequently, I disregarded it in favour of (IMHO) the very slightly less ugly approach outlined in the answer.