# Load xml file in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to load xml file into spring bean for further processing. I know that it is possible to load `properties` file simply defining a bean property in spring configuration file. Is it possible to do the same with xml file?

**edit**
For example I want to have a bean:

```
public class Bean {
   private File file
   public void setFile(File file) {
      this.file = file
   }
  //....
}
```

and in my configuration file I want to set it like this:

```
<bean id="bean" class="blabla.Bean">
   <property name="file" value="smth here"/>
</bean>
```

and then I want to parse that xml using DOM

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer-like class for use with Spring that accepts XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479855/is-there-a-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-like-class-for-use-with-spring-that-acc)

Comment: And also see [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer reads from XML File (Apache Commons Configuration)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163838/propertyplaceholderconfigurer-reads-from-xml-file-apache-commons-configuration)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question--are you talking about properties, or you want to, inside a Spring bean, load an XML file, and just want to define *which* file in your config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by changing the parameter type to a Resource - more details in [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html). You can get the file handle from the resource object

```
public class Bean {
   private File file
   public void setFile(Resource resource) {
      this.file = resource.getFile()
   }
  //....
}
```

and in the configuration file you can  set it like this. You can use classpath: if the file is part of a jar in your classpath. If it is outside you will need to use the file:

```
<bean id="bean" class="blabla.Bean">
   <property name="file" value="file:path to file"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer already supports xml property files via the [DefaultPropertiesPersister](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

The xml file format for the properties is as below.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
    <properties>
        <entry key="key1">Value 1</entry>
        <entry key="key2">Value 2</entry>
    </properties>
```

you can use

```
  <context:property-placeholder 
  location="classpath:/com/myProject/spring_prop.xml" />
      <bean id="bean" class="org.MyBean">
         <property name="key1" value="${key1}" />
      </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your configuration file to following,

```
<bean id="bean" class="blabla.Bean">
   <property name="file" ref="file"/>
</bean>

<bean id="file" class="java.io.File">
   <constructor-arg type="string"><value>C:\myfile.xml</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```