# import resource from user home directory

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, system-properties

I'd like to import a xml resource from users home directory:

```
<import resource="${user.home}/beans.xml" />
```

But this one does not work (placeholder is not replaced).

The [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?25677-Use-of-a-env-variable-as-a-path-to-a-prop-file-how-to-simplify-the-definition&highlight=propertyplaceholderconfigurer) does not give me a way to do that?! Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer-like class for use with Spring that accepts XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479855/is-there-a-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-like-class-for-use-with-spring-that-acc)

Comment: How do you specify list of context files to be loaded? Maybe it could be done there, would work with web.xml and env variables for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify the absolute path for the same.

```
Resource res1 = ctx.getResource("file:///c:/test.txt");
```

Comment: the solution must be platform independent.